# Running AdonisJS on C9.io

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, c9.io, adonis.js

I'm trying to create a new Node.JS app using the Adonis framework. I'm using c9.io as my IDE.

I've succesfully installed everything and created a new project. But when I run it (using `npm run dev`) c9.io keeps showing me the "No application seems to be running here!" message.

The `.env` file is set for port `3333` for default. But I also tried changing it to `8080`, and nothing changed.

Anyone managed to run AdonisJS on c9.io before? Thank you!

Comment: Are you running the app on localhost or on 0.0.0.0? Local host won't work on Cloud9 so you'll need to use 0.0.0.0 or `process.env.IP` (which will be the same thing).

Comment: Ooh. I'll try that. Just one question, can I call that variable (process.env.IP) inside the .env file? Or should I just hardcode 0.0.0.0

Comment: That was it! (side note: you cannot use the process.env variable there). Add this as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are running the app on 0.0.0.0, not localhost. Localhost won't work on Cloud9 so you'll need to use 0.0.0.0 or `process.env.IP` (which will usually be the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

I created a github for installing AdonisJS on c9 for anyone using this Framework on Cloud 9, as I imagine more people will run into issues installing Adonis on c9.

https://github.com/Devitgg/Cloud9-Adonis-JS-Framework-Installer